# Why urllib returns garbage from some wikipedia articles?

Tags: python, urllib2

```
>>> import urllib2

>>> good_article = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia'
>>> bad_article = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India'

>>> req1 = urllib2.Request(good_article)
>>> req2 = urllib2.Request(bad_article)
>>> req1.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')
>>> req2.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')
>>> result1 = urllib2.urlopen(req1)
>>> result2 = urllib2.urlopen(req2)

>>> result1.readline()
'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">\n'
>>> result2.readline()
'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\xec\xfdi\x8f$I\x96\x18\x08~\xee\xfe\x15BO\x06+\x82\xeefn\xa7\x9b[D\x855<<\x8e\x8c\xcc8\x9c\xe1\x9e\x99l6{\x15bf\xeaf\x1a\xae\xa6j\xa5\x87{x\x12\x1cT-\xb0 \xb1\xc0\x00\x0b4\x81\x01wg?\x10S\xe4\xee\x92\x98\x9d\x9ec\x01\x12\x8b]\x02\xdd5\x1f8\x1c\xf07\xd4\xd4\x1f\xd8\xbf\xb0\xef\x10\x11\x155\x15\xb5\xc3#\xb2"\xbaf\xea\x087\x95KEE\x9e<y\xf7\xfb\xf9\xdfz\xfa\xf6\xf4\xe2O\xcf\x9e\x89y\xb6\x08\xc5\xd9wO^\xbd<\x15{\x8d\xc3\xc3\x1f\xba\xa7\x87\x87O/\x9e\x8a\xbf\xff\xf5\xc5\xebW\xa2\xddl\x89\x8bDFi\x90\x05q$\xc3\xc3\xc3go\xf6\xc4\xde<\xcb\x96\x0f\x0f\x0fonn\x9a7\xddf\x9c\xcc\x0e/\xde\x1d~\xc0\xb1\xda\xd8Y\xfdldV\xcf\xe64\x9b\xee\x8d\xfe\xf8\xe7\xf4\xc2PF\xb3\xc7{~\xb4\'\xa6A\xf2x/\xcc\x92=\xf1a\x11F\xe9c\xc7\xd0\xed\xe1p\xc8#R\x7f_N\xe1O\x16d\xa1?z\x19M\x03)\x1a\xe2\x87\xe0*X\xfa\xf0\xfb@ds_\\&\xbe/\xfchr;\tc*\xfe\xf9!\xb7\xff\xe3\x9f/\xfcL\n'
```

Seems that the reason is not in headers because I tried exactly the same headers as my browser sends and urllib2 still returns this garbage.

Most of the pages returned normally

Comment: I can't reproduce here, both articles retrieve identical content until the page title.

Comment: I got everything fine. Not sure how you ended up seeing the garbage.

Comment: these are the exact lines I write =). Probably there is wrong encoding somewhere in process due to my non-english locale

Comment: There is no encoding/decoding being done when you fetch headers. It is very rare that your locale affects anything in Python unless you explicitly say so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not an environment, locale, or encoding problem. **The offending stream of bytes is gzip-compressed.** The `\x1f\x8B` at the start is what you get at the start of a gzip stream with the default settings.

Looks as though the server is ignoring the fact that you didn't do

`req2.add_header('Accept-encoding', 'gzip')`

You should look at `result.headers.getheader('Content-Encoding')` and if necessary, decompress it yourself.

Comment: The server is supposed to send the gzipped content, only if you send the Accept-encpding: gzip in the first place. He is not sending it here.

Comment: Thank you! But it is strange... sometimes server returned plain text, and sometimes gzip-ped

Comment: @Senthil Kumaran: looks like it is really gzip. "1F 8B 08" is magic number for gzip: http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html

Comment: @Senthil Kumaran: Your comment appears to paraphrase what I said: """Looks as though the server is ignoring the fact that you didn't do etc etc""" -- what is the point that you are trying to make?

Comment: result.headers.getheader('Content-Encoding') == 'gzip' =)

Comment: @John, Sorry, I did not read your response properly. You did mention that fact that Server is ignoring the fact. You were right and I missed this point in your answer.

Comment: You could use the [`requests` library](http://python-requests.org) and have it automatically handle Content-Encoding compression for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is something else causing you a problem. That series of bytes looks some encoded content.

```
import urllib2
bad_article = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India'
req = urllib2.Request(bad_article)
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')
result = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print result.readline()
```

resulted in this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

which is correct.

Comment: Hm, thanks for posting. Then it is probably some environment problems.. I'm running on win7, Python 2.7, Windows codepage '1251'. Will search in this direction

Answer (score 0):

Do a "curl -i" for both the links. If its coming fine, there is no environment problem.